# Flask-admin UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

When executing my Flask application I get the following warnings:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py:1324: UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset: password
  warnings.warn(text)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py:1324: UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset: new_password
  warnings.warn(text)
 * Restarting with stat
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py:1324: UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset: password
  warnings.warn(text)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py:1324: UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset: new_password
  warnings.warn(text)
```

I've normally used form_excluded_columns to remove unwanted fields from my form, but this time I have a hard time to get rid of those errors.

Here's my view:

```
class AdministratorView(sqla.ModelView):
    page_size = 10

    column_searchable_list = (
        'username',
        'description'
    )

    column_list = (
        'username',
        'apikey',
        'description',
        'active'
    )

    column_exclude_list = list = (
        'apikey',
        'source'
    )

    form_excluded_columns = (
        'source',
        'photos'
    )

    column_labels = {
        'apikey': 'API Key'
    }

    form_widget_args = {
            'apikey':{
                'readonly':True
            }
    }

    form_create_rules = (
        rules.FieldSet(('username', 'password', 'description'), 'Personal'),
        rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
    )

    form_edit_rules = (
        rules.FieldSet(('username', 'description'), 'Personal'),
        rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
        rules.Header('Reset password'),
        rules.Field('new_password')
    )

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created is False:
            if form.new_password.data:
                model.password = generate_password_hash(form.new_password.data)

    def scaffold_form(self):
        form_class = super(AdministratorView, self).scaffold_form()
        form_class.password = fields.PasswordField('Password', [validators.Required()])
        form_class.new_password = fields.PasswordField('New Password')
        return form_class

    def is_accessible(self):
        if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
            return login.current_user.has_role('admin')
```

The purpose of this view is to have a single, required Password-field on the create form and a optional "New password"-field on the edit-form. I understand that the warnings arise when I don't include password/new_password in form_create_rules and form_edit_rules, but adding those fields to form_excluded_columns doesn't fix it.

Any tips on how I can get rid of the warnings?

**Edit**:

I suppose I should rather use get_create_form and get_edit_form instead of only scaffold_form. One benefit is that this makes it easier to override each form separately. Can I simplify this further? Should I do requirement validation like this or add nullable=False to the database schema (SQLAlchemy)?

```
class AdministratorView(sqla.ModelView):
    page_size = 10

    column_searchable_list = (
        'username',
        'description'
    )

    column_list = (
        'username',
        'apikey',
        'description',
        'active'
    )

    column_exclude_list = list = (
        'apikey',
        'source'
    )

    form_excluded_columns = (
        'source',
        'photos'
    )

    column_labels = {
        'apikey': 'API Key'
    }

    form_widget_args = {
            'apikey':{
                'readonly':True
            }
    }

    form_create_rules = (
        rules.FieldSet(('username', 'password', 'description'), 'Personal'),
        rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
    )

    form_edit_rules = (
        rules.FieldSet(('username', 'description'), 'Personal'),
        rules.FieldSet(('roles', 'apikey', 'active'), 'Permission'),
        rules.Header('Reset password'),
        rules.Field('new_password')
    )

    def get_create_form(self):
        form = self.scaffold_form()
        form.username = fields.StringField('Username', [validators.Required()])
        form.password = fields.PasswordField('Password', [validators.Required()])
        return form

    def get_edit_form(self):
        form = self.scaffold_form()
        delattr(form, 'password')
        form.new_password = fields.PasswordField('New Password')
        return form

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created is False:
            if form.new_password.data:
                model.password = generate_password_hash(form.new_password.data)

    def is_accessible(self):
        if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
            return login.current_user.has_role('admin')
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will help: [How can I avoid Flask-Admin 2.1 warning "UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091818/how-can-i-avoid-flask-admin-2-1-warning-userwarning-fields-missing-from-rulese)

Here's the relevant code from that answer:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'Fields missing from ruleset', UserWarning)
    admin.add_view(UserView())
```